# problem with task with arrays and pointers

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I have a task:

In the main code, declare a two-dimensional array [ 5 ][ 8 ]
(declaration on this matter).
Save the setter setting, which will set the individual coefficient values ​​according to the scheme (values ​​decrease from 40 to 1).
The parameters of the function are two pointers. The first pointing to the first element, the second pointing to the last element.
There can only be one loop inside this function!
Save the printing configuration, which will be displayed on the screen. A function parameter can be translated into a two-dimensional array, with a const modifier.
Here it's classic, two loops to print.

In the main code:
• declare a two-dimensional array, • enter the setting configuration
• correct printing effect

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void set2(int *a, int *b)
{
    int start = 40;
    for(int *p = a; p < b; p++, start--)
    {
        *p = start;
    }
}

void print3(const int tab[][])
{
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<8; j++)
        {
            printf("%3i", tab[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main()
{
    int tab[5][8] = {0};
    set2(tab, &tab[4][7]);
    print3(tab);

    return 0;
}
```

I get several errors and I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong. Could you help me? Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Have you considered starting at the "last" node and assigning 40, 39, 38... _backwards_? To avoid UB by stepping out of the array, it might be better to use the counter instead of the pointer as the loop condition... `start > 0;`

Comment: try `void print3(const int tab[][8])`

Comment: @tstanisl yes now the first error disappeared thank you!

Comment: there is still this error:      main.c:30:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘set2’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   30 |     set2(tab, &tab[4][7]);
      |          ^~~
      |          |
      |          int (*)[8]
main.c:6:16: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[8]’
    6 | void set2(int *a, int *b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are two issues.

The first is in `set2`, where you need to change `p < b` to `p <= b`, since you want to modify the last element, `tab[4][7]`, too. Furthermore, you need to send `&tab[0][0]` as the first parameter since you want a pointer to the first element.

Second, as the compiler suggests, 'declaration of ‘tab’ as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first'. You must change `void print3(const int tab[][])` to `void print3(const int tab[][8])`.